# Redireccionar dominio / subdominio a IP con puerto

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dominio

Tengo un servidor dónde alojo todas mis webs, es un servidor privado y tengo IP fija.

El problema es que tengo una única IP, el puerto 80 va para un servidor y el 8082 para el servidor que tenemos para alojar las webs, el otro es para otros temas de web.

Ahora quiero poder redireccionar un dominio **www.dominio.com** a la IP **111.111.1.1:8082**

Mi duda es que, tras investigar mucho como hacerlo no logro realizar la configuración.

En principio en el dominio, debería poner mi IP pública con el puerto y luego en servidor un htaccess para que redirija según el dominio desde el que se accede ¿no?

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que, tras hacer click en un enlace, se siga viendo el dominio? Ahora llega bien, escribo www.dominio.com y veo correctamente la web en mi servidor y sin puerto, pero en el momento en el que hago click en los enlaces, se va esta mascara, y veo de nuevo la IP publica. Necesito saber como reescribir la URL para que aparezca siempre el dominio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No puedes usar ProxyPass en .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). La documentación dice que es únicamente aplicable al contexto:

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory

Por tanto, lo que debes hacer es crear un virtual host, para poder redirigir **www.dominio.com** a la IP **111.111.1.1:8082**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dominio.com
    ServerAlias www.dominio.com

    ProxyPass / http://111.111.1.1:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://111.111.1.1:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo y te comento si me surge alguna pequeña duda.

Comment: Una cosa, al realizar este proxy, cambiaría la IP al realizar ese proxypass? O se seguiría viendo en el navegador midominio.com??

Comment: Tu seguirías viendo midominio.com, pero Apache te redirige de forma transparente a 111.111.1.1:8082

Comment: Perfecto gracias.

Comment: Funciona bien, pero solo en la pantalla de inicio, en el momento que pincho algún link se ve la IP pública, he probado con la opción ProxyPreserveHost On, con esta opción conserva el host, pero parecen no cargar ni los css ni los js.

Comment: @Diego proba ver el codigo fuente de la pagina y busca los css, es posible que  hay un problema al cargar