# ¿Cómo redireccionar puerto 80 de mi URL a 8081 en AZURE?

Tags: azure, puertos

Tengo una maquina virtual y dentro de ella una aplicación corriendo en el puerto 8081, necesito que cada vez que se acceda al DNS de mi Maquina virtual con puerto por defecto 80, se redireccione al puerto 8081. Algo he leído acerca de los equilibradores de carga, pero no consigo resultados. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @FranciscoGutiérrez, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: tu pregunta es demasiado amplia , pero igual te puedo recomendar hacer el redireccionamiento con apache (proxyPass), seria algo como [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36388/28035)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo con un tutorial que te va a servir.

[Tutorial Load Balancer Port](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal)